# How to upgrade Ubuntu from an ISO image

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, upgrade

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 now and want to Upgrade to Ubuntu 11.04. The problem is my net connection is very slow and I can not do a network upgrade from the "Updates Manager".

So, is there a way that I can download the Ubuntu upgrade as an bootable CD image and upgrade from it?

Comment: **UPDATE:** It is **strongly** recommended to not attempt to upgrade in this manner, skipping intermediary releases. Upgrades to **10.04 LTS** should be only to **10.10** (*no longer supported*), or directly to **12.04 LTS**.

Comment: did you try burning the iso onto a disk then loading it into your dvd drive and installing it from their, after booting from dvd drive once the iso is burned onto disc?

Comment: is it absolutely necessary for you to upgrade via the iso? the software centre provides a decent and safe manner of upgrading without ruining your existing installation

Comment: Actually my internet connection is not stable and it may be disconnected in the middle of the process. But I got the ISO using a download manager.

Comment: More over it would be very useful for enterprises which may have more than one instance of Ubuntu to upgrade.

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux/340171#340171

Comment: Note it is fine to do this for 13.04 to 13.10 etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Download the **alternate** installation CD
2. Burn the ISO to a CD and insert it into the CD drive of the computer to be upgraded. 
   If the ISO file is on the computer to be upgraded, you could avoid wasting a CD by mounting the ISO as a drive with a command like:

> ```
> sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom  
> sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-11.04-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom
> ```
>
> (make sure you use the actual filename of the iso you downloaded ^^^^ )

1. A dialog will be displayed offering you the opportunity to upgrade using that CD.
2. Follow the on-screen instructions.

If the upgrade dialog is not displayed for any reason, you may also run the following command using Alt+F2:

```
gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```

Or if you're using Kubuntu run the following command using Alt+F2:

```
kdesudo "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```

Comment: This way, can we upgrade latest versions of Ubuntu like 14.x 16.x ?

Answer (score 15):

Just make a bootable USB or CD/DVD and boot it up as you would install ubuntu. When you are asked what you want to do just select "Upgrade...":
[image: Option]

Comment: In the question I have mentioned that I don't want to use usb or cd fro this purpose.

Comment: How does this differ from  'do-release-upgrade'? I say this because I'd like to upgrade a release by CD without loosing any programs or settings for a computer that is off the grid. In my experience using the upgrade as you have suggested was never better than with 'do-release-upgrade'.

Comment: Was the "upgrade" feature removed from latest live ISO? It was not displayed when I tried to upgrade my broken installation https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085665/broken-dependencies-after-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-upgrade

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so since `cdromupgrade` file is missing or not available, the next best thing is to create a LiveUSB and go on from there. Since you're upgrading from 13.04 the entire process should be rather flawless.

1. Open the Dash and open the **Create Startup Disk ** option. This opens a window, from where you can choose the iso file and destination.
2. Now select the 13.10 iso file and a usb (remember to use the erase disk option before you mount the image) and create your startup disk.
3. Now, upon re-booting you should boot directly into the USB. Select the install Ubuntu 13.10 option.
4. The installer window would present a number of options to you depending on the other OSes present in your hard drive.
5. Choose the `Upgrade to 13.10 option`. This should get you going and ready for 13.10.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I got `org.freedesktop.UDisks.Error.Inhibited: Daemon is inhibited` error when I want to erase the usb drive.

Comment: is it mounted? please make sure that it is not mounted.

Comment: I'm commenting from 13.10 thanks for your help but I think using the software updater would be better.

Comment: It would be, the system is designed to handle all sorts of dependencies. But as long as you have a clean install of 13.10, its okay. Have fun using 13.10! 
:)

Comment: Good to see that the LiveUSB worked for you @A.Karimi. It did for me too, because I had similar issues with having a stable internet connection. Also, it will prove to be useful, as you rightly suggest, for installation on multiple systems.

Answer (score 2):

You can boot ISO files from Grub.  However, I think you will need to have the ISO file on another medium (such as another hard drive, or a USB/CD/DVD)

Booting from Grub2:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Installing over the network:
[Is it possible to install Ubuntu through network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339427/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-through-network)

And finally:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD

Though if you have your /home in a separate partition (or any other non-standard filesystem configurations like that), this will not work....  You must reinstall, rather than upgrade.

Though you can simple upgrade incrementally through the normal method:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade
though you may have to check your settings.