# How do I upgrade from media/iso?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upgrade Ubuntu from an ISO image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image)

I have downloaded & burnt iso of Ubuntu v11.10 & was trying to upgrade my current installation (running v11.04) when i ran into a strange issue. The installer (when i boot from media) does not detect my existing Ubuntu setup. It detects my Windows 7 installation & gives me 3 choices but NO upgrade choice. When i try upgrading in (while running) Ubuntu - it tries to download the upgrades again.

Isn't there a method where i can upgrade my existing installation just using the media?

Comment: Ubuntu requires anexisting installation to be updated befire it can be upgraded to next version. Try `$ sudo apt-get update && upgrade` from Terminal. If it gives issues, please try the commands one after the other as : fist, `$ sudo apt-get update` and then `$ sudo apt-get upgrade`.