# How to Ubuntu upgrade from 10.10 to 12.10 32-bit

Tags: 10.10, 12.10, upgrade, xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upgrade Ubuntu from an ISO image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image)

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed.  Kindly let me know if there are upgrades for changing my version of Ubuntu.
Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: The issue here is Ubuntu **10.10**, and not using online vs. ISO image to upgrade.

Comment: The suggested **duplicate** is not 'best practise' and may not be suitable in this instance.

Comment: Also related: [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 2):

You *could* only upgrade from **10.10** to **12.10** by first upgrading to **11.04**, **11.10**, then **12.04 LTS**, and finally to **12.10** ..

[Maverick: end-of-life reached on April 10, 2012](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/04/10/ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-end-of-life-reached-on-april-10-2012/)

However, Ubuntu **10.10** (Maverick) is no longer supported, and so upgrading from 10.10 to **11.04** is also **not** supported.

- Any upgrade should only be attempted if your are fully updated for the current release. *Put more simply, the start and end points are both moving targets.*
- Any upgrade problems may directly relate to behavior of the unsupported release you are updating from. *The upgrade can be attempted, but lacks 'support'.*

---

Once you have your data and settings backed-up, you should do a **fresh** install of Ubuntu **12.04 LTS** on your PC. There may be initial issues with drivers, but this should mostly be resolved by doing an update.

Once you have **12.04 LTS** working, then *try out* (but do **not** immediately install) Ubuntu **12.10**. This should also work on your PC, but will in turn be replaced by **13.04**, etc.

I have successfully run **12.04.1 LTS** on an HP Mini netbook (Atom processor, 1GB RAM) or ex-corporate desktops (P4 2.8GHz, 1GB RAM).

---

---

***UPDATE:***

Actually **11.04** is also no longer supported.

[Natty: reaches end-of-life on October 28, 2012](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/09/17/ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-reaches-end-of-life-on-october-28-2012/)

The problem is that for releases that are no longer being maintained, upgrading **from** these releases may have issues which are **not** likely to be resolved. The release being upgraded **to** also needs to be supported, otherwise the user is on their own.

**Ubuntu** / Canonical do support longer usage (without upgrading), but only for the **Long Term Support** (LTS) iterations. These are usually released **only** every two years.

Comment: How would you suggest this is done? *Please provide reference information.*

Comment: That **option** keeps you on (for example) **10.04 LTS** until **12.04.1 LTS** is available. *You do **not** get prompted to upgrade to 10.10, 11.04, 11.10, etc.* It does **not** provide a 'magic' method of skipping (non LTS) releases.

Comment: Then I think you got a problem: You should say that since **11.04** is not supported, upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04 is not supported. It feels weird when you are saying that since 10.10 is not supported, upgrades to 11.04 aren't supported too....

Comment: See update, above.

Comment: Now I can finally upvote it

Answer (score 1):

For upgrading Ubuntu, go to the Update Manager. It has to tell you that a Ubuntu update is available since you are still on 10.10. If it does not tell you this, go to Software Sources to ensure that you allow the system to propose you Ubuntu updates when they are available. Once you see that a Ubuntu update is available on the Update Manager, click on the button near it and follow the instructions. Note that it might propose you intermediate upgrades before 12.10. I especially think to 12.04 LTS.