# How do I upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 13.04 with an .ISO image?

Tags: upgrade, mount, 13.04, iso

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my system. I want to upgrade it to Ubuntu 13.04. I want to do this upgrade using an .ISO image of Ubuntu 13.04 and without a USB drive.

I tried [How to upgrade Ubuntu from an ISO image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image) .

But it didn't work for me.

After running the proposed commands, I didn't have any alerts about updating.
I also don't understand the `gksu` part of the solution.

Also, is this possible to do by using a networked computer? By this I mean the .ISO file is on another computer.