# How to update Ubuntu to i386 from terminal or a .ISO file?

Tags: installation, updates, 32-bit, iso

All right. I re-install my Ubuntu 64bits, but now it's very slow. I'm downloading the 32bits .iso from Transmission and I want know if has any possibility to "update" from this iso file. If don't, can I update to 32bits from terminal?

I don't have any other DVD to put the iso... that's why I am asking!

I'm using **13.04 Raring Ringtail**.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39243/can-i-switch-from-ubuntu-amd64-to-ubuntu-32bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "update" from 64bit to 32bit or vise versa, either from terminal or from ISO.

In fact, you cannot update from an ISO without making a Live DVD/USB and booting from the live media.

**You have to do a fresh install.** You can [making a Live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) (1GB USB will do) and boot from the USB and then install.

Comment: Hum... Interesting. After the installation, can I use the USB stick after that? Like... Erase the Ubuntu in it and use normally?

Comment: You can erase or reformat the USB stick and use it as a normal stick. However, I'd keep it around as it comes handy once in a while. If you keep the Live USB, when the next version of Ubuntu is released, you can reformat and use it again for the next version.

Comment: Hum. Thanks! Do you know some video that explain how to does it?

Comment: You are welcome. Do you mean a video of how to make a Live USB? There are plenty if you search youtube. Such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMQdy7lDDNY If you feel the answer is correct, please put a green check mark to indicate that. It will help others.

Comment: I do not think you can update from the desktop iso at all, usb or not. All you can do with the iso is a fresh install as the iso does not have the actual packages. Also I doubt the 32 bit version is going to be any better. Identify your hardware (video card, wireless) and/or try an alternate to Unity (k/x/lubuntu). You can upgrade form with the iso http://askubuntu.com/questions/290201/how-do-i-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-13-04-with-an-iso-image.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I never said one could update... only fresh install. However, I agree that a 32bit version will probably not help with speed. A separate question about slowness with information about the hardware, CPU, RAM, speed of hard drive, along with the ones you mention, video card, Wifi etc. may be more useful.