# How to Update 12.04LTS to 13.04?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, upgrade

I want to upgrade my OS from 12.04LTS to 13.04,but the update manager only shows me 12.10 as an upgrade option available.
What do i do now?? Please suggest me a safe and legal way.

Comment: I think you find some help here,

http://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image

Comment: The preferred options are either backup and clean install or upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04.  The updater is only designed to go from one release to the next or one LTS release to next LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You can go from 12.04 to 13.04 directly, but a flawless system would not be guaranteed, you might have issues of the device dropping WiFi signals and similar stuff. It'll be better if you update to 12.10 and from there to 13.04

The reason behind this is that the packaging scripts that come with every release have a great deal of conversion to do, converting old settings and formats into new and current formats. If you jump from a release to another, this'll become quite difficult for the script to manage.

That's why, by convention you can upgrade from one LTS version to another, in this case from 12.04 to 14.04, or from one release to the next release, i.e. 12.04->12.10->13.04.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must upgrade to 12.10. Complete the install, boot, and then upgrade to 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to skip immediate releases at upgrade to a higher version, If you really want this, I think you find some help here,

[How to upgrade Ubuntu from an ISO image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image)