# How to update Ubuntu 13.04 from 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

I want to update my Ubuntu version. but how I can update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to skip immediate releases at upgrade to a higher version, If you really want this, I think you find some help here,

[How to upgrade Ubuntu from an ISO image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image)

You will find additional info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322127/how-to-update-12-04lts-to-13-04/322151#322151) too.

Comment: would you please tell me what is the difference between two version?

Comment: @Scotia, There are lot of differences such as interface differences, software versions security fixes and much more. You can just google it and findout. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended but it is possible with:

sudo do-release-upgrade