# Installing Ubuntu on Windows XP without a disk

Tags: windows-xp

I have an older laptop with xp and want to install Ubuntu on it,but my cd/dvd drive does not work. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Can the laptop boot from an USB/Flash/Pen drive? If not, it is still possible but not easy. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/339427/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-through-network You may also try Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu. Lubuntu runs better on older PCs.

Comment: You can also use the network installer:

See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339427/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-through-network?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different flavours of Ubuntu. You can download Ubuntu or one of the other flavours, listed [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives). Depending on your laptop's hardware, you may want to Download [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) instead of Ubuntu, as they are 'light' and use fewer resources.

---

You can use USB, but your laptop has to support this.

1. Download [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)
2. Download [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)

   *You will probably need the 32-bit version, but your laptop **may** also be able to run 64-bit, please post more info about your laptop so we can check it for you.*
3. Open Rufus
4. Use the following settings:

   - Device

     - your USB drive
   - Partition scheme and target system type

     - MBR partition scheme for BIOS and UEFI computers
   - File system

     - FAT32 (Default)
   - Cluster size

     - 16 kilobytes (Default)
   - New volume label

     - Ubuntu
   - Uncheck `Check device for bad blocks`
   - Check `Quick format`
   - Check `Create a bootable disk using`

     - Select `ISO Image`

       - Click on the CD drive icon and select the Ubuntu ISO you've downloaded
   - Check `Create extended label and icon files`
5. Click `Start`

**Note:** this will destroy all your data on your USB drive.

---

If USB booting doesn't work for you, you can also try Wubi.

1. Download [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
2. Download [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)
3. Open Ubuntu's ISO file using 7-Zip and extract all files to a new directory

   *For example `Desktop\Ubuntu`.*
4. After the extraction is complete, open the directory you just created
5. Double click on `wubi.exe` and follow the instructions

Answer (score 0):

sure you can do it with usb. Burn the iso file to usb . The plug the usb and go to bios setup of your computer and change the boot order, give usb as first perioty and you will be good to go.

My personal experience : I have one very old pc, installed Ubuntu just like you to taste it out, but i was not satisfied with it. Beacuse it did not run at full potential. If you have newer pc then you can dualboot ubuntu along side with Windows to enjoy the ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Please google to use 'wubi', installing Ubuntu from inside a Window system. You may want to install a 32 bit flavour of Ubuntu, instead of 64 bit. Maybe 12.04 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the oficial instructions ont the website: [**How to create a bootable USB
stick on Windows.**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

But, as @user68186 said, you may try the Lubuntu. This one works better and faster in old machines. To install Lubuntu from USB follow this guide:  **[Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)**