# How do I dual boot install Ubuntu without a USB drive or CD/DVD?

Tags: boot, software-installation, uefi, windows

I have a UEFI device with no USB flash drive or CD/DVD. Very much new to ubuntu so unsure what to do. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Your question does not show your skill level. Installing manually (without a DVD/USB) is not safe, easy, or fast for a beginner. There are plenty of traps and opportunities for catastrophic mistakes. Advice: Borrow a friend's empty USB flash drive for the afternoon.

Comment: You can not install ubuntu out of the blue. You need a LiveCD or LiveUSB to install it. During installation, you can choose to install side-by-side and that gives you possibilty to dual boot with your existing OS.

Comment: Check this out although might not work for you https://askubuntu.com/questions/339427/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-through-network

Comment: Just about everyone has a smart phone that can be used to install Ubuntu.

Comment: What OS are you dual booting with? If Windows, you can boot Ubuntu Live using  **Grub2 for Windows** and install Ubuntu as dual boot from there. see https://askubuntu.com/a/1290304/43926

Answer (score 0):

### Install Ubuntu from Smart Phone using DriveDroid

https://www.drivedroid.io/

DriveDroid simulates a USB thumbdrive or CD-drive by using the Mass Storage capabilities in the Android/Linux kernel. ISO/IMG files that are stored on the phone can be exposed to a PC like any other USB thumbdrive capabilities. That includes allows booting from the drive as well. The combination makes it quick and easy to do OS installations, rescues or have a portable OS on the go.

My experience with DriveDroid can be found here: [How to install Ubuntu using a smart phone as the installation media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/how-to-install-ubuntu-using-a-smart-phone-as-the-installation-media)