# Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 from ISO image

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, iso

Having installed Ubuntu 13.04 I've downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 ISO to upgrade from it. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image) answer doesn't work because there is no `cdromupgrade` file in the mounted ISO disk.

How can I upgrade 13.04 to 13.10 using the ISO image or CD/DVD media?