# Is it possible to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 over FTP

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, 14.04, ftp

How do I upgrade from 13.10 to 14.10 using ftp. http goes through a proxy and we a limited to 500M per week. FTP is not limited.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your sources file pointing to ftp instead of http
Use following command to edit your configuration:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In most cases its enough to change http:// in every line to ftp:// but I would strongly encourage to make a backup copy of sources.list first. Also I would check is ftp connection available on your repository server. Simply get a URL from sources file, change http:// to ftp:// and paste into your web browser.

Comment: Thanks... I have tried this however the "installer" download fails. If I change to http the installer downloads fine.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the upgrade will use the FTP protocol, you basically need to update your software sources to use a ftp mirror.

To do that the best approach is to use the Ubuntu **Software Center**.

1. Open Software Center
2. Open the Edit -> Software Sources... menu
3. Select Others in the Download from list
4. Finally choose a mirror supporting the ftp ptotocol (it will update /etc/apt/sources.list automatically)

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I have tried a few ftp servers and each time when I try to do a update-manager -d I get "System Up to Date" with no option to upgrade to 14.04

Comment: Since 14.04 is now released, remove the `-d` option to run  update-manager (-d was for development)

Comment: Weird, I get the same message "The Software on this computer is up to date"... no option to upgrade... using ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in

Comment: Try with `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

Comment: Same thing with `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`?

Comment: No Luck... Can only do an upgrade if I choose http :-(

Comment: In that case what you could try is download the iso over ftp and try to upgrade from a live USB to 14.04 (See http://askubuntu.com/questions/369838/upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-10-from-iso-image)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you actually want to upgrade to 14.04, as that is the current release.
NOTE: Year.Month = 2014.April == 14.04
It is Strongly Recommended that you should do a Full Install, rather than an upgrade, especially that you are moving to a Long Term Support release.
This actually makes things easier, as you can download the full install image via FTP: http://ftp.daum.net/ubuntu-releases/14.04/
There are other FTP Ubuntu download mirrors which can be found via your favorite search engine.

Comment: yes... I want to upgrade to 14.04... thanks for pointing it out. Do not want to do a full install as I loose all the apps I collected over the past few months unless there is a way can save this from being deleted? If I do an install without formatting the disks, is it safe?

Comment: As of this date, after installing and checking out 14.04, my advice would actually be to postpone such upgrade/migration until at least v14.04.2. Let's just say it needs some work still, and I say this as someone who has used Ubuntu since v7.04. Aside from that, AptOnCD provides a wonderful way to backup all the programs, big and small, that you've built into your arsenal. AptOnCD simply marks down all the packages that Synaptic would use to reinstall at a later time and even different Ubuntu (or Debian) version.