# Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 from ISO

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, lts

Can I upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 *LTS* to Ubuntu 18.04 *LTS* from already **downloaded** 18.04 LTS ISO ?

If can, How?

Comment: This question has similar Q & A already at https://askubuntu.com/a/781410/39004

Comment: »»already downloaded 18.04 LTS ISO«« : The default live DVD contains no packages → Not usable for an upgrade.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

The official upgrade from LTS to LTS is possible when the 1st point release gets released (18.04.1). Current target for the release of the 1st point release is July 26th.

You can do `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` on a fully updated 16.04 if you want to upgrade from command line. Only do that when you know how to restore your backup.

Due to the changes between 16.04 desktop (unity) and 18.04 desktop (gnome 3), I would re-install anyways. Make sure you can restore a backup for your personal data.

Comment: I saw we can still install Unity (3D compiz) on it, compiz woobly, full screen modes (3d scaled) and many other features are really cool and useful, I will 1st upgrade a notebook, if all is good I will the desktop, cant wait for July 26th :)