# Upgrade Kubuntu/Ubuntu using ISO (Without fresh install)

Tags: kubuntu, iso, do-release-upgrade, livedvd

Is it still possible to upgrade Kubuntu /Ubuntu without wiping the root partition?

I mean something like this: [Upgrading ubuntu from LiveDVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCjgB.png) instead of `do-release-upgrade`.

This method will be handy in case of unstable internet.

(My current running systems are Kubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I want to upgrade to 18.04 as soon as it's released)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image  . I am not sure if you can update from an .iso any longer or not.

Comment: No, The whole point of this question is different. "Is it still possible " is the actual point to this question.

Comment: @SudarshanKakoty: Please have a look at my response below on why it's not *advised* to do that any more... (It is possible,but you'd need 1.1 TB/4.3GB=256 DVDs to do it successfully and that is if you have no PPAs installed!)

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidFoerster This question has been resolved, I added my own answer with a screenshot below :)

Comment: I just wanted to upgrade Ubuntu to next release from a live DVD the way we could able to do in Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're not a forum but focus on questions and answers that hopefully have bearing beyond a single person. Therefore we strive to have high quality answers *and questions* that are clear as to what they aim to achieve. That you found a solution to *your specific* issue doesn't change that lack of clarity as to what you actually want to achieve. See my previous comment as to the reason (imho).

Comment: This question already has an answer here: -- That's not an answer to my question. I used the word "Still".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No,

That is not advised any more...

#### Why?

The CD/DVD Image will not have the [entire 1.1TB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors) of Ubuntu Repository files available, so doing an upgrade from CD would give you a partially upgraded system at best.

#### Sorry!  :-(

Answer (score 2):

I got it using the `Kubuntu-devel-release-upgrade` command:

[image: Development Release]

Comment: Could you share more details please?