# upgrade the existing xubuntu LTS 20.04 installation to LTS 22.04 from CD

Tags: upgrade, cd

Hi Is there a way to upgrade the existing xubuntu LTS 20.04 installation to LTS 22.04 from CD? I have multiple installations, and don't want to repeatedly download the new version.

Comment: You can re-install as a *quick* means of *release-upgrade*, which is non-destructive & will auto-re-install the *manually installed* packages (if the packages are from Ubuntu repositories in the new release), but that isn't exactly what you are after, and isn't QA-tested to work with any 3rd party packages you have installed.

Comment: Edited: Deleted email address. This is the wrong place to solicit help via email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade Ubuntu from an ISO image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image)

Answer (score 0):

add the CD path to software & update other software by adding the details for the CD. then you should be able to update via CD.
my entry is ...

cdrom:[Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS *jammy jellyfish* -release amd64 (20220809.1)]

tick the box and reload the software updater then use it to check for updates and it will load the updates from the CD ...

Comment: There It just says insert CD. Doesn't allow me to enter the path. On inserting CD also, nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks but that too didn't work

Comment: Its not showing tick box even after entering the path of the cdrom using sudo apt-cdrom